# C# is to Visual Studio as PHP is to... anything?

Tags: c#, php, vb.net, visual-studio

Now that I've started learning Microsoft's languages and using Visual Studio, any time I code in PHP I feel like a second-class citizen. Is there anything for PHP developers that comes close to what VS offers for VB and C# developers?

Comment: There are so many... Even Dreamweaver has limited IDE support for PHP.

Comment: Ugh... Dreamweaver. Been there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [phpDesigner 7](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner.php)
- [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/features/php/)
- [phpED](http://www.nusphere.com/products/phped.htm)
- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) (by [dphendricks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/512922/dqhendricks) & [Gotosleep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/178533/gotosleep))
- [VS.PHP](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php) (by [Gabe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310574/gabe))
- [Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/)
- [PHPStorm 2.0](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/index.html) (by [tcrosley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324631/tcrosley))

...[more](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=PHP+IDE&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=e7c6912739a11d79)

[Article on IDEs for PHP and comparisons](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/02/11/the-big-php-ides-test-why-use-oneand-which-to-choose/)

(Funny `lmgtfy`.com is blocked. Must have been a tad overused...)

Comment: Eclipse, Zend Studio, Notepad++, TextWrangler (though Notepad++ and TextWrangler are more of code highlighters rather than full blown IDEs)

Comment: I actually did try Google but I must be off today because all I was getting was information on getting PHP into VS, with so-so results.

Comment: Use a bit.ly or url shortner and that overcomes the lmgtfy block :) http://tinyurl.com/4bat6lf

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [VS.PHP](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php) is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be unhelpful, but I've never heard of one, but then again Visual Studio is very good. Eclipse may be of help to you: http://www.eclipse.org/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/

Zend Studio of course.

Comment: Yes it uses Eclipse as a base platform, but it has everything in one package set up specifically for PHP.

Comment: supports Linux, Windows, and Mac.

Comment: I think you can also install a Zend package into already installed versions of Eclipse to give it similar features.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be windows based? I'm pretty sure if you were working on linux then VIM and EMACS would have a lot to offer...you probably wouldn't even need a mouse :-)

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains [PHPStorm 2.0](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/index.html) (Coming soon; version 1.0 currently [for sale](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/buy/index.jsp)).  Code completion, code inspection, GIT and Mercurial support.  I have no connection with JetBrains, just a satisfied customer.

You can download a beta-test copy of PHPStorm 2.0 [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Web+IDE+EAP).

Answer (score 0):

I've always liked [PHPEdit](http://www.phpedit.com/en). From my last memory of using it some 3 years ago, it wasn't clunky like eclipse and had a pretty good "intellisense"